# How to pass all local variables when calling a method

Tags: ruby, local-variables

I am wondering if there is an easy way to pass all local variables when calling a method, instead of passing them one by one as parameters. I want the following:

```
class Greeting
  def hello
    message = 'HELLO THERE!'
    language = 'English'
    say_greeting
  end

  def konnichiwa
    message = 'KONNICHIWA!'
    language = 'Japanese'
    say_greeting
  end

  private def say_greeting
    puts message
  end
end

Greeting.new.hello
```

to show `HELLO THERE!`. But it returns an error: `NameError: undefined local variable or method 'message'`.

I tried `local_variables` to get all local variables as an Array of symbols. But I can't seem to access the actual variables because there seemed to be no Ruby method like `local_variable_get`.

**Background of the problem**

In my Rails application, I have a controller having three update methods  for different view files. All of them behave exactly the same (that they all will update a resource, show error if any, etc). Their only main difference are

1. template to be rendered when unsuccessful
2. redirect url when successful
3. flash success message

I only have three variables, so it really is indeed easy to just pass them as parameters, but I am just wondering if there is an elegant solution to this.

Comment: `message` should either be with `attr_accessor :message` or use an instance variable by prefixing it like `@message`. private methods have access to the same variables as public methods. the *private* and *public* only sets permissions for what other classes can use.

Comment: I do not want the variable accessible outside the class. putting attr_accessor :message will allow me to do `Greeting.new.message` which I do not want.

Comment: then use instance variable by prefixing message with @. or you can put the attr_accessor also as private and then it will be reachable only from inside the instance

Comment: No, there's no way to do it. Well, there's probably _some_ way to do it with the `binding` object, because ruby is like that -- but it will be overly complex and is not a good idea even if it's simple.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Local variables are there to do precisely not what you are trying to do: encapsulate reference within a method definition. And instance variables are there to do precisely what you are trying to: sharing information between different method calls on a single object. Your use of local variable goes against that.

Use instance variables, not local variables.

If you insist on referencing local variables between methods, then here is a way:

```
class Greeting
  def hello
    message = 'HELLO THERE!'
    language = 'English'
    say_greeting(binding)
  end

  def konnichiwa
    message = 'KONNICHIWA!'
    language = 'Japanese'
    say_greeting(binding)
  end

  private def say_greeting b
    puts b.local_variable_get(:message)
  end
end
```

You can't make it without passing any arguments, but you can just pass a single binding argument, and refer all local variables from there.

Comment: I am hoping I could not use instance variables because it will add them already in the memory instead of being garbage collected upon the end of the method. I also don't want these variables to be shared to other methods. But, if this seemed the only way to go, I willl accept your answer :)

Comment: Otherwise, you should pass them as argument. Avoiding that also goes against the language design.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about this binding! :D Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Make the message and language as instance variables.
Then you can access them inside the private method.

```
class Greeting
  def hello
    @message = 'HELLO THERE!'
    @language = 'English'
    say_greeting
  end

  def konnichiwa
    @message = 'KONNICHIWA!'
    @language = 'Japanese'
    say_greeting
  end

  private 

  def say_greeting
    puts @message
  end
end

puts Greeting.new.hello
```

Comment: If possible, I would like to use only local variables. Say there is a class which has 1000 variables being shared. That will add a big amount of memory to the object.

Comment: do some metaprogramming to build a commandline calling the method or generate a temporary common class you throw later away.

Answer (score 1):

Use instance variables. In your method `say_greeting` make sure you call the method `hello` first, otherwise the value of `@message` will be `nil`.

```
def hello
 @message = "Hello there"
end

def say_greeting
  hello #method call
  puts message
end
```